# Break down 1 liner javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I came across a JavaScript code that creates an array and fills it with numbers from 0-9.

The code is:

```js
var arr = Array.apply(null, {length: 10}).map(Number.call, Number);
console.log(arr);
```

The code above creates an array and pushes numbers from 0-9 in it.
I do not understand how it is working. I know all the methods that are used in this like `apply`, `map`, and `call` but still don't understand how it is working.

Can anyone please explain the working of code by breaking it into chunks? Like how step-by-step code is being executed and how it is resulting in an array that has numbers from 0-9.

Comment: You don’t understand it despite knowing all the methods? The MDN documentation describes how each of these methods works, in particular which arguments they accept, and what they all mean. So you _don’t_ understand the methods? Which ones do you not understand? The code itself is a needlessly confusing way to write the more idiomatic `Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, index) => index)`.

Comment: Sebastian, if you understand it well then explain the working part `.map(Number.call, Number)` with code before it.

Comment: I mean… it’s all explained in the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `map` accepts two arguments. The first one is a function that is called with three arguments. [`.call`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) accepts any number of arguments: the first one is the `this` value, the rest are the actual function arguments. The second `map` argument provides the necessary `this` context for `Number.call`. See [How does the "this" keyword work?](/q/3127429/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your code creates an array of 10 elements, all of which being `undefined` using the below code:

```js
Array.apply(null, {length: 10})
```

The above is like writing:

```js
Array(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, ... 6 more times ...)
```

This works because the object `{length: 10}` is array-like as it has a `length` property. Usually the second argument to `.apply()` is an array of arguments that you want to call the function with. However, as you're passing an object in this case, JS takes the length property and calls the `Array()` function with 10 `undefined` arguments, as the keys of the `{length: 10}` object don't define values for properties `0` to `9`.

Next, the array of 10 `undefined` values are mapped. When using `.map()`, the first argument is the mapping function and the second argument to the `.map()` method is the `this` argument, which indicates what `this` should refer to inside of the first mapping function. One way of looking at your map method is to rerwrite it like so:

```js
.map((element, index, array) => Number.call(element, index, array))
```

The `.map()` method will iterate through all of your 10 `undefined` elements, and for each element your callback will be invoked with the `index` of that element. When using `Number.call()`, the `this` for the `Number()` function call is set to `undefined` (ie: `element`). This doesn't impact how the call to `Number()` behaves as it doesn't rely on any particular value for its execution. As a result, the above `Number.call` method is the same as using `Number(index, array)`, where `array` is discarded, so it's simply performing `Number(index)`.

The second argument to the `.map()` method is to define the `this` binding for the first mapping function that you pass into the `.map()` method. When you pass `Number.call` as the mapping function, you're passing a reference to the `call` method defined on `Function.prototype.call`. The `call` method only knows what function it should invoke based on its `this` value defined when calling the `.call()` method. As you're only passing the `.map()` method a reference to the `call()` function, and not invoking it with `()`, the `this` is lost, and so you need to explicitly define what the `this` value is. That can be done by passing through `Number` as the second argument to your map method call.